# Can we extend the projectively extended real line with a single number that stands for division of zero by zero?

Tags: set-theory, theories-of-arithmetic

If we work within $\hat{\mathbb R} = \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}$, i.e. one point compactification of the real line.

We extend $<$ relation on $\mathbb R$ to $\hat <$ defined as:

$ x \ \hat{<} \ y \iff x < y \lor (y=\infty \land x \in \mathbb {R}^+ )\lor (x=\infty \land y \in \mathbb {R}^- )$

Accordingly, with respect to $\hat{<}$, any upwardly unbounded sequence in $\mathbb R^+$ converges in $\hat{\mathbb R}$ on $\infty$, and similarly any downwardly unbounded sequence in $\mathbb R^-$ converges in $\hat{\mathbb R}$ on $\infty$

Given an $n$-ary total surjection $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, we consider its multivalued-and total extension $\hat{f}:\hat{\mathbb{R}}^n \to \hat{\mathbb R}$, by setting $\hat{f}(a_1,...,a_n)\leadsto b$ iff there are sequences of (non-extended!) reals $(\alpha^1_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow a_1,..., (\alpha^n_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow a_n$ such that for each $i$ the expression $\beta_i:=f(\alpha_i^1,...,\alpha_i^n)$ is defined and $(\beta_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow b$. Here, "$\rightarrow$" refers to convergence in $\hat{\mathbb{R}}$ in the usual sense.

Let $\hat{\hat {\mathbb R}} =  [\hat{\mathbb R} \cup  \mathcal P (\hat{\mathbb R})\setminus \mathcal P_1(\hat{\mathbb R})] \setminus \{\varnothing\}$

Define a new relation $\in^*$ on $\hat{\hat {\mathbb R}}$ as:

$\begin {align} y \in^* x \iff &(x \in \hat{\mathbb R} \land y=x) \ \lor \\&(x \subseteq \hat{\mathbb R} \land \neg \operatorname {singleton}(x) \land y \in x)\end{align}$

Define: $x=[y  \mid \phi] \iff x \in \hat{\hat {\mathbb R}} \land  \forall y \, (y \in^* x \iff y \in \hat{\mathbb R} \land \phi) $

Now we extend each function $\hat f$ defined above to a function $\hat{\hat f}$   over   $\hat{\hat {\mathbb R}}$ as:

Define: $ \hat{\hat f}(X,Y) = [z \mid \exists x \in^* X \, \exists y \in^* Y :  \hat{f} (x,y) \leadsto z] $;

We define *Number*, abbreviated as $Num$, recursively as:

$\begin {align} Num(X) \iff & X \in \hat{\mathbb R} \lor \exists \hat{\hat f}, \exists A , \exists B :\\ & Num(A) \land Num(B) \land   \hat{\hat f} (A,B) =X \end {align}$

Now obviously we have:   $ 0\ \hat{\hat{/}} \ 0 = \hat{\mathbb R}$.

All of the known defined rules over $\hat{\mathbb R}$ shall be preserved with extended functions $\hat{\hat f}$ over $\hat{\mathbb R}$, but this system can additionally advance solutions to the undefined problems in $\hat{\mathbb R}$, like:

$$\infty \ \hat{\hat{+}} \ \infty = \infty \ \hat{\hat{-}} \  \infty = 0\ \hat{\hat{\times}} \ 0 \\ \infty \ \hat{\hat{\times}} \  0 = 0 \ \hat{\hat{\times}} \  \infty = 0\ \hat{\hat{/}} \ 0 \\ \infty\ \hat{\hat{/}} \ \infty =0\ \hat{\hat{/}} \ 0 $$

> 1. Is it consistent to have $0\ \hat{\hat{/}} \ 0$ as the only  *Number* that is not an element of $\hat{\mathbb R}$?

> 2. If the answer to 1. is to the positive, then is it provable in $\sf ZFC$?